# Laravel : How to filter nested list returned in controller

Tags: laravel, filtering

I have a controller that returns a nested list like this:

```
"items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "cat_id": 1,
        "title": "books",
        "orders": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "qty": 1,
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "user_id": 1,
            "qty": 4,
          },]
```

The controller looks like this:

```
function  get_orders($user_id){
    $items= Item::with('Order')->get();
    return $items;
}
```

Now, I want filter to and return only the detail for `$user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call like this

```
$items=Order::where('user_id',$userid)->whereHas('item')->get();
```

Make sure to write relation in Order Model

```
public function item(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
}
```

Or

```
$items= Item::whereHas('Order',function($query)use($userId){
$query->where('user_id',$userId)
})->get();
```

if both table data need to be in return then it should be like

```
$items= Item::with('Order')->whereHas('Order',function($query)use($userId){ $query->where('user_id',$userId) })->get();
```

Comment: I will check it and response

Comment: okay. initially i understood your question wrongly .so i think second answer fit to your problem

Comment: $items= Item::with('Order')->whereHas('Order',function($query)use($userId){
$query->where('user_id',$userId)
})->get();    if you need to fetch both data

Comment: @Sermedmayi.any issues still ?

Comment: $items= Item::with('Order')->whereHas('Order',function($query)use($userId){ $query->where('user_id',$userId) })->get();   what about this

Comment: I am not beside my work when comeback will check many thanks